# How to Calculate the Percentage Contribution Within Column in a Data Frame Using Pipe Function in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to calculate the column wise percentage contribution on each item.

I am unable to do that, I tried to do it, seems very complicated.

The dataset I am working with is given below:

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), `2019-01-01` = c(37, 
36, 45, 53), `2019-02-01` = c(3, 19, 14, 46), `2019-03-01` = c(28, 
2, 28, 28), `2019-04-01` = c(48, 70, 18, 16), `2019-05-01` = c(83, 
71, 58, 26), `2019-06-01` = c(85, 28, 83, 46), `2019-07-01` = c(60, 
20, 12, 77), `2019-08-01` = c(44, 66, 30, 99), `2019-09-01` = c(21, 
14, 31, 21), `2019-10-01` = c(26, 72, 72, 16), `2019-11-01` = c(15, 
96, 23, 100), `2019-12-01` = c(65, 0, 98, 66)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The expected output is given below:

```
structure(list(`Row Labels` = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), `2019-01-01` = c(0.2164, 
0.2105, 0.2632, 0.3099), `2019-02-01` = c(0.0366, 0.2317, 0.1707, 
0.561), `2019-03-01` = c(0.3256, 0.0233, 0.3256, 0.3256), `2019-04-01` = c(0.3158, 
0.4605, 0.1184, 0.1053), `2019-05-01` = c(0.3487, 0.2983, 0.2437, 
0.1092), `2019-06-01` = c(0.3512, 0.1157, 0.343, 0.1901), `2019-07-01` = c(0.355, 
0.1183, 0.071, 0.4556), `2019-08-01` = c(0.1841, 0.2762, 0.1255, 
0.4142), `2019-09-01` = c(0.2414, 0.1609, 0.3563, 0.2414), `2019-10-01` = c(0.1398, 
0.3871, 0.3871, 0.086), `2019-11-01` = c(0.0641, 0.4103, 0.0983, 
0.4274), `2019-12-01` = c(0.2838, 0, 0.4279, 0.2882)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Attached is an image of the excel snapshot with the intended calculation as well.

[image]

Please let me know how to approach this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  mutate(across(-`Row Labels`, ~.x / sum(.x)))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  `Row Labels` `2019-01-01` `2019-02-01` `2019-03-01` `2019-04-01` `2019-05-01`
  <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 X1                  0.216       0.0366       0.326         0.316        0.349
2 X2                  0.211       0.232        0.0233        0.461        0.298
3 X3                  0.263       0.171        0.326         0.118        0.244
4 X4                  0.310       0.561        0.326         0.105        0.109
# ℹ 7 more variables: `2019-06-01` <dbl>, `2019-07-01` <dbl>, `2019-08-01` <dbl>,
#   `2019-09-01` <dbl>, `2019-10-01` <dbl>, `2019-11-01` <dbl>, `2019-12-01` <dbl>
```

Comment: This case worked in this situation but for some reason when I write this in the actual situation I am trying to code for, it says the column which is in the position of `Row Labels` does not exist. Any idea why?

Comment: The syntax `across(-'Row Labels', ` means "apply the function across all columns except the one with the literal name `'Row Labels'`. You could replace that with the name(s) of the column(s) you wish to exclude, or use `across(-1,` to remove it by position (in that case the first column). You haven't described your situation so it's hard to know what would work best. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html for a collection of helpers to select the columns you want.

Comment: Yes. I was aware of that. I did replace it but it didn't work. I figured out why because the data frame I was working on was grouped and when it's grouped it didn't work and when I un-grouped it. The same thing worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("2019"), ~ .x / sum(.x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use -

```
df[-1] <- round(t(t(df[-1])/colSums(df[-1])) * 100, 2)
df

#  Row Labels 2019-01-01 2019-02-01 2019-03-01 2019-04-01 2019-05-01 2019-06-01
#1         X1      21.64       3.66      32.56      31.58      34.87      35.12
#2         X2      21.05      23.17       2.33      46.05      29.83      11.57
#3         X3      26.32      17.07      32.56      11.84      24.37      34.30
#4         X4      30.99      56.10      32.56      10.53      10.92      19.01

#  2019-07-01 2019-08-01 2019-09-01 2019-10-01 2019-11-01 2019-12-01
#1      35.50      18.41      24.14      13.98       6.41      28.38
#2      11.83      27.62      16.09      38.71      41.03       0.00
#3       7.10      12.55      35.63      38.71       9.83      42.79
#4      45.56      41.42      24.14       8.60      42.74      28.82
```

An easier to understand approach would be to use some kind of loop using `sapply` in base R or `across` in `dplyr`.

```
df[-1] <- round(sapply(df[-1], \(x) prop.table(x)) * 100, 2)
```

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(-1, ~round(prop.table(.x) * 100, 2)))
```

Comment: You could use `prop.table` directly on the whole chunk of `df` too, with a single assignment - `df[-1] <- prop.table(as.matrix(df[-1]), 2)`